# Relationship between intelligence of the most advanced species and planet size

Tags: aliens, intelligence

My world is similar to that of Contact (1997) with Jodie Foster, but hopefully more realistic  scientifically.

In order not to bump into hostile life on our bold adventures; more intelligent than us, completely unprepared, we might want to try hanging out with low IQ ET first. Would planet size be a factor? Immediately either side of the optimum zone for life, how would ET's IQ vary?

Comment: [Goldilocks Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumstellar_habitable_zone) refers to orbital position not planet size, please clarify. If you're making two different queries ask two different questions, you may not need the second depending on answers to the first.

Comment: Welcome! Please mind you are asking two different question: first, relation between planet size and intelligence of inhabitant, second relation between distance from star and intelligence of inhabitants. Since we enforce a 1 question per post policy, this makes your request too broad. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help].

Comment: Ok, planet size Goldilocks zone for life in general then, please, to extend the meaning for this world to planet size?

Comment: Please ignore the second (implicit, accepting of my ignorance) question about real world Goldilocks zone, and assume it only refers to planet size, not distance from the star

Comment: remove the superfluous part from the question. Questions have to be self sufficient, without requesting the reader to go through the comments. You can use the edit functions to change the text.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: IQ is not intended to serve as a comparison benchmark between species. It is actually not intended to be used as a comparison mark between human geographically or temporally distinct populations. By definition, the average IQ for a specific human population of interest is 100. It's always 100. The average IQ of 19th century French school pupils was by definition 100, and the average IQ for 21st century American high school seniors is by definition 100, but this says nothing about the relative intelligence of 19th century French school pupils and 21st century American high school seniors.

Comment: Is that an answer?

Comment: you have just removed the term Goldilocks, but the two questions are still there.

Comment: No they're not...

Comment: Planet size and either side of the habitable zone. They are still there.

Comment: No that's not what it says. It does not mention habital zone. There is no such association made with that term

Comment: optimum zone for life is not different from habitable zone

Comment: If you say so :) I have my answer now anyway, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship between the intelligence of a sapient species and planet is most likely the same as the relationship between intelligence and shoe size. In other words, not at all.

How would ETs IQs vary? Probably, a statistical distribution like that of a Bell curve.

Using planet size as a guide to the level of intelligence of any alien species to be able to meet and greet the lesser smart ones first, doesn't seem like a workable proposition. An interesting challenge to determine a way to find less intelligent alien species instead of running into the exceptionally brilliant ones.

In conclusion, forget planet size as an indicator of intelligence level.

Comment: Somewhere, somebody speculated about there being a restricted range of IQ to be expected for alien intelligent species. At least, before they have some kind of technological singularity.  The idea is that to evolve intelligence vastly more than you need to survive will be selected against because a bigger brain requires more energy (protein, calories, whatever) to grow and sustain.  Does it sound familiar?

Comment: @puppetsock Evolving bigger brains isn't easy. They're energy greedy, fragile, require long childhoods & growing times, and in viviparous mammals giving birth becomes extremely hazardous. All things selective pressures will work against, and yet there animals on Earth with bigger brains than humans. Oddly enough the brain-body ratio seems to be a more important indicator of intelligence.